# How to write a function that calculate x^16?

Tags: haskell

I have to write function for calculating x^16 and x^20 that uses the least amount
of multiplication steps with Haskell. It is not allowed to use the built-in exponentiation operator `^`. I`ve tried so many things,but nothing works... I already wrote it till x^8, i guess. What should i do as next?

```
square :: Integer -> Integer  
square x = x * x

pow :: Integer -> Integer  
pow x = square (square x)   

pow1 :: Integer -> Integer   
pow1 x = pow (pow x)
```

Comment: Your `pow1` function is already `x^16`. If you want `x^20`, just multiply `x^16` and `x^4`, which is your `pow` funciton.

Comment: In fact `(^)` will normally use a binary algorithm and already use the minimum number of multiplications.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Repeated squaring uses a small number of multiplications, but not the minimum number for all exponents. In fact, a [slightly generalized version of the problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addition_chain) of finding the minimum number of multiplications needed is NP-complete.

Comment: Possibly leverage the quite ancient [Indian Exponentiation Algorithm](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/107708/origin-of-square-and-multiply-algorithm).

Answer (score 1):

Let's formulate this the general way. (As dfeuer comments, this is actually not *quite* the general way, because sub-products could also be shared in other ways, not just in squaring; but for the given examples it's good enough.)

```
data Exponentiation
  = Variable
  | Multiplication Exponentiation Exponentiation
  | Squaring Exponentiation
 deriving (Eq, Show)

exponPower :: Exponentiation -> Int
exponPower Variable = 1
exponPower (Multiplication l r) = exponPower l + exponPower r
exponPower (Squaring e) = 2 * exponPower e

nMultiplications :: Exponentiation -> Int
nMultiplications Variable = 0
nMultiplications (Multiplication l r) = 1 + nMultiplications l + nMultiplications r
nMultiplications (Squaring e) = 1 + nMultiplications e
```

Now we can write a brute-force generator for finding the best possible strategy of multiplying to get a given power:

```
import Data.List (minimumBy)
import Data.Ord (comparing)

bestMulStrategy :: Int -> Exponentiation
bestMulStrategy 1 = Variable
bestMulStrategy n = minimumBy (comparing nMultiplications)
                        $ sqStrats ++ mulStrats
 where sqStrats
        | even n     = [Squaring . bestMulStrategy $ n`quot`2]
        | otherwise  = []
       mulStrats
            = [ Multiplication l r
              | nl <- [1..n-1]
              , let l = bestMulStrategy nl
                    r = bestMulStrategy $ n-nl ]
```

That *works*, but it's very inefficient because we keep re-calculating the optimal strategy for the smaller sub-powers over and over, so already for 16 it takes a long time. A simple fix is to *memoise* the function:

```
import Data.MemoTrie

bestMulStrategy :: Int -> Exponentiation
bestMulStrategy = memo best
 where best 1 = Variable
       best n = minimumBy (comparing nMultiplications)
                        $ sqStrats ++ mulStrats
        where sqStrats
               | even n     = [Squaring . bestMulStrategy $ n`quot`2]
               | otherwise  = []
              mulStrats
                   = [ Multiplication l r
                     | nl <- [1..n-1]
                     , let l = bestMulStrategy nl
                           r = bestMulStrategy $ n-nl ]
```

And then we learn, unsurprisingly,

```
> bestMulStrategy 16
Squaring (Squaring (Squaring (Squaring Variable)))
```

For 20, it's a bit more interesting:

```
> bestMulStrategy 20
Squaring (Squaring (Multiplication Variable (Squaring (Squaring Variable))))
```

I don't think this is the unique optimum, but it certainly is *an* optimum (5 multiplications).

What's left to be done is, implementing those strategies as Haskell functions. That could be done with Template Haskell, but I think it's more instructive for you to do it yourself.

Comment: I don't understand your last paragraph. I thought you've already implemented everything in this answer as Haskell functions?

Comment: @WillNess well, and `Exponentiation` value is not an exponentiating function. It would be easy to define a function that uses is as kind of _instructions to follow_, either on runtime or with TH, but I suppose for the OP it's more useful to just hand-code it.

Comment: ah, thanks, that clarifies it. it could be just one function though, to execute a strategy. I don't think the Q actually requires separate functions for each power.

Comment: How do you know you're not double-counting a shared product?

Comment: @dfeuer hm.... I don't. Ok, this is actually not optimal in general, though I'm still pretty confident it _is_ optimial for 16 and 20.

Comment: I would guess that the place to start is with a naive representation of addition chains. How long could it take to iteratively enumerate all the chains of length `k`, where `k` is quite small? If you want, you can merge chains that result in identical result sets, but I'm not sure it's worth the trouble. When you reach the first `k` that produces 20, you're done.

Comment: Nice development, but I can't help but think about how useless this answer probably is to the OP given their apparent level of experience.